# Dynamically add Select2 to Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

why when i try to add select2 to new row the new select2 failed to initialize (it shown as select html tag).
[image: sELECT2]

Here's my code to create the table :

```
<table id="tbldet" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" style="width:100%;margin:0 auto;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><p>Nama Barang</p></th>
      <th><p>Harga</p></th>
      <th><p>Qty</p></th>
      <th><p>Total</p></th>
      <th style="width:50px"><p>Aksi</p></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <select class="select2" name="det_brg" style="width:100%;">
          </select>
      </td>
      <td>10000</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>930000</td>
      <td><span class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

javascript function to initializeSelect :

```
function initializeSelect2(selectElementObj) {
  selectElementObj.select2({
    width: "80%",
    tags: true,
    language:"id",
    ajax: {
        url: "controller/barang_list.php",
        dataType: "json",
        type:"GET",
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                search: params.term
            }
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                  return {
                    id:item.id,
                    text:item.text
                  }
                })
            };
        },
        cache: false
    },
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    dropdownParent:$("#form-data")
  });
};
    $(".select2").each(function() {
      initializeSelect2($(this));
    });
```

here's the code to add new row :

```
//create new row
$("#add_row").click(function(e) {
  //new row
  $("#tbldet").append(
    '<tr>\
        <td>\
            <select class="select2" name="det_brg" style="width:100%;">\
            </select>\
        </td>\
        <td>10000</td>\
        <td>4</td>\
        <td>930000</td>\
        <td><span class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></span></td>\
    </tr>'
  );
  var newSelect=$(this).closest("tr").find(".select2");
  initializeSelect2(newSelect);
})
```

i suspect there's problem with finding new 'select2' component on new row, but when i use `alert(newSelect)` it didn't show NULL / Undefined

Comment: a jQuery selector will never be null or undefined, if it doesn't find an element, it returns a jQuery object of length 0. What does it show when `console.log(newSelect)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct, your code will never find the new `.select2` element. The reason has to do with the way `.closest()` works. You can investigate that here:

https://api.jquery.com/closest/

But in the mean time:

**Change**

```
var newSelect=$(this).closest("tr").find(".select2");
```

**TO**

```
var newSelect=$("#tbldet").find(".select2").last();
```